# Teamcity vcs trigger quiet period until previous build finish

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.1

I would like my trigger to start on svn commit but only after previous build had finished.

It is implemented to some extent with quiet period but there are disadvantages I'd like to omit:
1. it could be situation build has already finished but we are still waiting for quiet period to finish
2. it could be situation build has not yet finished but we are starting new build because quiet period had finished.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume (since you didn't specify) you want the next build to start only after the previous build has finished because there is some shared resource that they are using (e.g. for integration tests).

TeamCity has a setting to limit the number of simultaneously running builds, whether they are manually run or started by a trigger. Set the following option on the first page (General Settings) of your build configuration to "1":

> Limit the number of simultaneously running builds (0 — unlimited)

**Edit:** TeamCity 8.0 announced today has added support for [Shared Resources](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Shared+Resources) which allows you to define external resources and quotas for use across more than one build configuration.